# How to iterate thru the list and find out the missing blocks in java 8?

Tags: java, collections, nested-loops

We have a response JSON that comes in below format. There is a need for us to process this json efficiently and log some of the the item Ids that are missing some important information such as options block(at least for debugging purpose). Included the sample response below.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "itemId": "xxx",
            "priceList": [
                {
                    "price": 0.0,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "priceType": "yyy"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "itemId": "xxx",
            "priceList": [
                {
                    "price": 0.0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "itemId": "xxx",
            "priceList": [
                {
                    "price": 0.0,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "price": 0.0,
                            "priceType": "yyy"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "itemId": "xxx",
            "priceList": [
                {
                    "price": 0.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to log the missing item ids as below

```
items.forEach(item -> {
if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(item.getUoms().get(0).getPricingOptions())) {
    log.info("price options is missing for item {} ", item.getItemId());
}
```

});

Is there better/faster way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you'd call this better, but you can use streams to implement this:

```
items.stream()
    .filter(it -> it.getUoms().get(0).getPricingOptions().isEmpty())
    .forEach(it -> log.info("price options is missing for item {} ", it.getItemId()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I got a NPE with the above change. But I slightly modified the code as filter(item -> CollectionUtils.isEmpty(item.getPriceList().get(0).getOptions())) and it worked. In my opinion it is certainly elegant and readable than my previous approach.Thanks again!